# Doing post inside a jsp file not working in jboss7

Tags: jsp, jsf, jboss, jboss7.x, icefaces

In my root path from war, I have a file customerSelection.jsp (in my LoginServlet I redirect to this page in a specific condition):

```
resp.sendRedirect("/customerSelection.jsp");
```

Inside this jsp file, I am loading a jsf file using this in the body:

```
 <jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/jsf/account/customerSelection.jsf" />
```

and it's loading nice. The issue is that when I do POST in icefaces after this file is loaded, from any control, it says it cannot find `/WEB-INF/jsf/account/customerSelection.jsf`.

This worked perfectly in jboss 5, but it's not working after I did upgrade to jboss 7.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

JSF takes the request URL which has hit the `FacesServlet` in the current request as `<form action>` URL. I'm not sure how/why the old approach works for you, I don't have JSF 1.x at hands now, but you should actually be performing a full JSF request, not a JSP request which in turn forwards to a hidden JSF source. The `FacesServlet` is hit for the first time with the forward.

Instead, use

```
resp.sendRedirect("/customerSelection.jsf");
```

and

```
<jsp:include src="/WEB-INF/jsf/account/customerSelection.jsp" />
```